# Update objects within an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Original array (form[id].values.sections) made up of different objects

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    1. 0: 
        1. attachments: Array(0)
            1. length: 0
            2. [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
        2. body: "" // How do i update the values here without the original array being converted into an object
        3. [[Prototype]]: Object
    2. 1: {body: '', attachments: Array(0)}
    3. 2: {body: '', attachments: Array(0)}
    4. length: 3
    5. [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

If i use the following method to update body, it turns into an object as shown below

```
        updatedSections = {
          ...form[id].values.sections,
          0: {
            body: contentBody, attachments: form[id].values.sections[0].attachments,
          },
        };
```

updatedSection becomes an object.

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}}
    1. 0: 
        1. attachments: Array(0)
            1. length: 0
            2. [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
        2. body: "<p>Content update here</p>"
        3. [[Prototype]]: Object
    2. 1: {body: '', attachments: Array(0)}
    3. 2: {body: '', attachments: Array(0)}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: btw what browser outputs those numbers before all the properties? It makes it really hard to see their names...

Comment: Body is actually a string but if i update it using the method shown, it will convert the original array into an object. I'm using chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've converted your array into an object by using

```
updatedSections = { ... }
```

If you want it to remain an array, you need to use array notation e.g.

```
updatedSections = [
  {
     body: contentBody, 
     attachments: form[id].values.sections[0].attachments,
  },
  ...form[id].values.sections.slice(1)
]
```

Comment: May i ask if we need to update the second and third array as well, would it work?

Comment: @user8779054 you mean the second and third values in the array? You could still use something similar, and use slices to get the non-updated values, but then it might be simpler to just use `updatedSections = form[id].values.sections` and then individually update the elements using for example `updatedSections[0] = {
     body: contentBody, 
     attachments: form[id].values.sections[0].attachments,
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it becomes an object. Because updatedSections is an object. (you have initialize it with {}).

```
  updatedSections = { // <-- here
      ...form[id].values.sections,
      0: {
        body: contentBody, attachments: form[id].values.sections[0].attachments,
      },
    }; // <-- here
```

Below is the correct way to access body property in the array.

```
form[id].values.sections[0].body = <your_new_content>;
```

If you don't want to update the original array directly, make a copy of the `sections` array and update the desired properties in it. Hope this makes sense.